# How to select a subplot of the timeVariation function in OpenAir

Tags: r, openair

I want to produce a plot showing diurnal variation per weekday and month. The `timeVariation` function produces the desired plot, along with three other subplots. This makes the subplot at the top hard to read:

```
library(openair)
mary <- importAURN(site = "my1", year = 2000)

timeVariation(mary, 
              pollutant = 'no2',
              type = 'month')
```

[image]

I would like to plot only the top subplot showing weekdays. I tried using `plot(myOutput, subset = "day.hour")` as described in the
[OpenAir manual](http://www.openair-project.org/PDF/OpenAir_Manual.pdf):

```
plot(timeVariation(mary, 
              pollutant = 'no2',
              type = 'month'),
     subset = 'day.hour')
```

But that produces this:
[image]

This plot may contain the correct data, but the replication of the labels makes it overcrowded and very confusing. Is there a way to extract just the plot I want, formatted as shown in the top image?

Comment: Is the top plot an annualized Mon-Sunday? So, keeping that in mind, would `just_give_me_this <- timeVariation(mary, 
              pollutant = 'no2',
              type = 'month')[1]` or [[1]], followed by plotting just_give_me_this? A scan of the documentation suggests it might get you there.

Comment: Thanks. Playing around with the indices, I can extract the individual plots with `[[1]]` or `[[1]][1]`, `[[1]][2]`, `[[1]][3]`, and `[[1]][4]`. Unfortunately, the formatting of the plot I want is still messed up.

Comment: Ok, cool, so now we're beyond processing and down to plotting instructions. Clarifying 'messed up' as in you clarify as it is your presentation aesthetic we're addressing here. Just downloaded `openair` and will take a look after dog walk.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, the problem is that when plotting only the month x weekday subplot it does not look like in the first image above but like the second image with every combination of weekday and month in the axis labels.